# Access a user control children in xaml views

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, uwp, uwp-xaml

I don't know the best way to title and describe my problem, sorry if something is not clear or I'm using the wrong words, I'll try:

I have the following user control:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="FormValidationUwp.Controls.ValidatingTextBoxUserControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Grid>

    ....

    <TextBox x:Name="MyText"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             TextChanged="MyText_OnTextChanged"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Header="{x:Bind Header, Mode=OneWay}"
             PlaceholderText="{x:Bind PlaceholderText, Mode=OneWay}"
             Text="{x:Bind Text,Mode=TwoWay}"
             IsSpellCheckEnabled="{x:Bind IsSpellCheckEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"
             InputScope="{x:Bind InputScope, Mode=OneWay}"
             Style="{x:Bind TextBoxSyle, Mode=OneWay}" />

...
</Grid>

</UserControl>
```

And I use it in my views like this:

```
 <controls:ValidatingTextBoxUserControl x:Name="NameTextBox"
                                           PlaceholderText="Name"
                                           IsMandatory="True"
                                           MandatoryValidationMessage="{x:Bind ViewModel.ErrorMandatory}"
                                           Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.UserBindable.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                           TextBoxSyle="{StaticResource BodyTextBoxStyle}" 
                                           Width="300" />
```

What I would like to do is to access the textbox extra properties in XAML, something like this:

```
<controls:ValidatingTextBoxUserControl x:Name="NameTextBox"
                                               PlaceholderText="Name"
                                               IsMandatory="True"
                                               MandatoryValidationMessage="{x:Bind ViewModel.ErrorMandatory}"
                                               Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.UserBindable.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                               TextBoxSyle="{StaticResource BodyTextBoxStyle}" 
                                               Width="300" >
            <ValidatingTextBoxUserControl.MyText x:Name="NameTextBox"
                                               Placeholder="Name"
                                               Text="aaa">                
            </ValidatingTextBoxUserControl.MyText>
        </controls:ValidatingTextBoxUserControl>
```

Is it possible? If yes, how do I do that?
Thanks a lot and feel free to suggest/edit my post to make it more clear.

P.S.
instead of down vote my question as someone already did, if you read I already explained that I don't know a better way to explain it, feel free to comment some suggestion

Comment: Hi, you can do it. It is a little bit complicated. You can add dependency properties in your control and implemnet setters and getters of this properties to set new values directly to your TextBox or bind values to the text box.

Comment: @macieqqq thanks, it's already what I'm doing at the moment, I would like something more flexible without to need to add dependency properties manually for all the properties that I need :(

Comment: So you alreadhy have access to the TextBox properties across the specified binding. If you realy need it you can pass your TextBox control as a dependency property but think twice about encapsulation.

Comment: @macieqqq ok I'll try also this way thanks, I tired without success, maybe I did something wrong. thanks

Comment: Probably not the best way, but you can add x:FieldModifier="public" to XAML children of your ContentControl and then you will be able to access them through code like YourContentControl.ChildrenName.

Comment: @MarianDolinský this looks really interesting, I'll take a look later, thanks !